# ng.checked in angular.js not working with HTML appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

It's a todo app. When you type something in the input, new code is appending to `div.container`. And then the "newborn" checkbox with `ng-checked="checkAll"` (which should check all checkboxes in `container`) not responding to changes in the main checkbox with `ng-model="checkAll"`. In that time, already existing secondary checkbox with `ng-checked` is responding to the main one. How to fix that?

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<h1 class="heading">TODODO!</h1>

<div class="container">
    <form ng-submit="newTask()">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkAll">
        <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" placeholder="What tododo?">
    </form>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkAll">
</div>
</body>
```

Script:

```
var App = angular.module("App", []);

App.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = [];
    $scope.newTask = function () {
        if ($scope.text) {
            $('.container').append("<div class='task'><input type='checkbox' ng-checked='checkAll'/>" + this.text + "</div>");
            $scope.list.push(this.text);
            $scope.text = '';
        }
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that both checkboxes are using the same model. Create a different model for each one and also ng-checked. If you don't want to affect any other checkboxes when you check one, then that checkbox show have her own property names. For example:

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<h1 class="heading">TODODO!</h1>

<div class="container">
    <form ng-submit="newTask()">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="doNotAffectSecond" ng-checked="doNotAffectSecond">
        <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" placeholder="What tododo?">
    </form>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="doNotAffectFirst" ng-checked="doNotAffectFirst">
</div>
</body>
```

This is general, you can customize it. In your case, if you check first checkbox, `checkAll` will be true and the second one with be automatically checked.

Comment: The goal is to force main checkbox to affect all the secondary check's.

Comment: `In that time, already existing secondary checkbox with ng-checked is responding to the main one. How to fix that?` Well sorry, but then what do you want to fix?

Comment: It's alright, mb I'm not clear enough :)
I meant that the input that goes right after the `form` is responding to the main check, while those who created by script (in `div.task` tag) not responding — and this is the issue.

Comment: Well is not responding because you show that checkbox only when form is submitted so the `div task` doesn't know about the ones from above.